# Fastest way to compare sha1 checksum in clipboard with sha1 of local file using OS X bash

Tags: macos, bash, clipboard, checksum

I'm thinking maybe it's combining `shasum` and `diff` with a pipe or something...

I want to know the fastest way to compare an sha1 checksum copied from a website to my clipboard against the sha1 checksum of a local file which I've downloaded from the same site to verify its integrity.

For example, I have the sha1 string `94f7ee8a067ac57c6d35523d99d1f0097f8dc5cc` in my clipboard from the [Raspberry Pi NOOBS download page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/) and I want to compare it against the checksum for the `NOOBS_v1_9_0.zip` file using the Terminal app, and I don't want to have to create a new file from the clipboard contents.

*I think it's bash 3.2 (It's OS X 10.11.4)*

Comment: See: [Accessing the OS X Clipboard from the Command Line](http://osxdaily.com/2009/12/09/access-the-clipboard-from-the-command-line/)

Comment: Add content of clipboard, content of local file and bash version to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus Sure thing—I see I need to clarify.

Comment: @Cyrus In regard to your first comment: I can just press `⌘` + `v` to get the string in the Terminal without additional software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a command something like this in bash:

```
if [[ $(pbpaste) == $(shasum file | awk '{print $1}') ]]; then echo 'matches'; fi
```

Using that you could create a function like this  (eg. add it to your `~/.bash_profile`):

```
shachk () { 
    if [[ $(pbpaste) == $(shasum "$@" | awk '{print $1}') ]]; then echo 'match'; fi ;
}
```

So on the commandline you could simply input:

```
$ shachk somefile
```

Then it would compare it against the hash on your pasteboard.

<sub>**EDIT**: A *slightly* improved version of the function which returns the file path, matches/failed, and colorizes the output.</sub>

```
shachk() { 
    [[ $(pbpaste) == $(shasum "$@" | awk '{print $1}') ]] \
    && echo $1 == $(pbpaste) $'\e[1;32mMATCHES\e[0m' && return; \
    echo $1 != $(pbpaste) $'\e[1;31mFAILED\e[0m' ; 
}
```

Comment: This is definitely along the lines of what I'm thinking, but using `shasum` produces output that includes not just the checksum, but also the file name.

Comment: The awk within the command eliminates the filename, so only the hash is compared.

Comment: This worked great; thanks! I wish there were a built-in way to do this without `awk`. I guess it seems silly to me that `shasum` outputs the file name again when I already specified it.

Comment: You could also add an "else" statement to display unmatched cases.  E.g. ; then echo 'matches'; else echo 'Failed!' ;

Comment: Top notch snippet @I'L'I Thank you